# Permanently changing permission of FireWire device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, chmod, ubuntu-10.10

I just setup a FireWire audio interface. Everything works fine, except for I need rw-rw-rw- permissions on /dev/fw0. I can always `sudo chmod 666 /dev/fw0` just before setting the thing up, but then it will be gone on the next rebooting.

The solution to modify `/etc/udev/rules.d/020-permissions.rules` (which is for Ubuntu Breezy) doesn't go well for Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick because there is no **/etc/udev/rules.d** directory.

What should i do in order for /dev/fw0 to come up with 666 permissions?

Thanks in advance,
Ilya

Comment: it exists for me...on 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found out how to do this!

First, we need to make a /etc/udev/rules.d directory:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/udev/rules.d
```

Next we have to define a new rule:

```
sudo -s
echo 'KERNEL=="fw*", GROUP="video", MODE="0664"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/80-firewire.rules
exit
```

And finally we have to add our username to the 'video' group. The permissions will be set after reboot.